# Should I be writing the majority of my code in a controller or the delegate?

Tags: iphone, xcode, delegates, controller, ios5

I was using Xcode 4.1 and after upgrading to 4.2, things started to become out of date.  I am using many examples from different books, such as Big Nerd Ranch Guides, which do not use Storyboards and the Windows-Based Application had been changed to "Empty" Application.

With these new changes, I feel like the books and tutorials I had been using to start have become outdated.  In many of these examples, they say to write the methods and variables in the delegate header files for 4.1.  With the new 4.2 Xcode, there is an AppDelegate and ViewController.  Should I still be writing the methods and class members in the AppDelegate, or should I be now writing them in the Controller file?

I am confused.  Does Apple now want us to create our controller and reference it through the delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app is run, it creates an instance of `UIApplication`. You want to know things that only the `UIApplication` object knows (did we just get switched to the background? did we just open?) so you use the delegate pattern to get it. When you start a new project Apple starts you off with an already-assigned App Delegate. You can open up `MainWindow.nib` and inspect your App Delegate to see how it is connected to your UIApplication instance (File's Owner, in this case).

In general you only want to put code in there that has to do with the basic functionality of your app. Launch, quit, go to background and come to foreground are when you'll be doing things in the App Delegate.

Most everything else should go in your view controllers or model objects. Since 'delegate' is just a design pattern, your view controllers can be delegates of other objects. For example, if you present a `UITableView`, you will assign a view controller as it's delegate in order to respond to events such as selection and scrolling. Your app has many delegates, but it only has one App Delegate.

Answer (score 0):

The `AppDelegate` is really just a "launcher" for your app. Ie: You shouldn't be writing much code in it at all.

If you're concerned with "set up" code, do it in your View Controller, under `viewDidLoad`.